# Zero-inflated or two-part models: how to interpret main effects of categorical fixed effects?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, zero-inflation, glmmadaptive

I'm running a hurdle lognormal model using the GLMMadaptive package in R. Both the continuous part as well as the zero-part have categorical variables defined in the fixed effects. I would like to run an ANOVA on these categorical variables to detect if there is a main effect.

I've seen that using the glmmTMB package you are able to separately run an ANOVA on the conditional model and the zero-part model separately, as is demonstrated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474561/how-to-get-p-values-for-the-zero-inflated-part-of-a-model).

Is there a similar strategy available for the GLMMadaptive package? (The glmmTMB does not support hurdle lognormal models as far as I understood). Perhaps using the `joint_tests` function from the emmeans package? If so, how do you define that you want to test the zero-part model? As `emmeans::joint_tests(hurdlemodel)` only gives the F-tests for the conditional part of the model.

Or as an alternative method, could you compare the fit of the models where you exclude the variable of interest against a the full model, as is demonstrated for the relevance of random effects in [this vignette](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html)?

Many thanks!